# CosmosDB GeoSpatial Query not returning results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a document that has the following properties

```
"Latitude": 13.7461464,
"Longitude": 100.535355
```

Now my own coordinates where I am currently are

```
13.7604
100.5238
```

I would assume the following query would return the above document but it is not

```
SELECT c.id
FROM c
WHERE ST_DISTANCE({"type": "Point", "coordinates":[c.Latitude, c.Longitude]}, {"type": "Point", "coordinates":[13.7604, 100.5238]}) > 1
```

I get no error message just no matching results but for sure the distance is more than 1 meter so why am I not getting a result back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format for the coordinates. It should be:

```
{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [lon, lat]}
```

As found in the [RFC7946 specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-9). Note the longitude appears before the latitude in the array.